# 'In the Fox Theater' or 'In the Fox theater' or 'In The Fox Theater'

Tags: nouns, articles, capitalization

I am confused over the use of 'the' and capitalization.

Comment: 3 almost identical questions in 12 minutes? Little wonder no-one is too bothered about answering.

Comment: There's a similar landmark building in Westwood near UCLA called the *Fox Theater, Westwood Village* or the *Fox Village Theater*.  The article is not part of the name but all references to the building include it.  This is different from *Holmby Hall*.  Thus I would say, "I'll look for you at Holmby Hall, and if I don't see you, I'll expect to meet you at the Fox Village Theater."